# SVN - most efficient way to work on the same files

Tags: svn

Me and my colleague are in SVN and we use it a lot. It's perfect for consolidating changes whenever we make changes to the site. We often get into trouble though when we're editing the same file.

With our site structure, we have a styles.css that contains all the aesthetics of the site. Since we're both frontend dev, we both edit it at the same time frequently. We encounter problems (because of human error) during this scenario:

- Person A and B "svn up" and get the latest `styles.css`
- Person A starts working on `styles.css`, updates and commits changes
- Person B now updates his/her version (remote) to get the latest copy.
- [Error comes in] Person B **forgets to download the latest copy** and start s working on his outdated copy. He then commits that and essentially erases everything person A did.

It's a human error both parties are guilty of forgetting. Now we wonder if there's a more efficient way of editing the same files in SVN. Or maybe we're doing it wrong and we'd like to know how to do it right. We are both new to SVN.

**EDIT**
-I don't think we're all in the same page. I know how to replicate the "out of date" but I don't think that's the case. If Person A commits then I try to commit *right after* (svn st + svn commit), I will get the out of date error.

Our situation is (in sequence):

Person A: svn up > svn st > svn commit

Person B: **svn up** > forgets to download updated file/upload old file without A's changes > svn st > svn commit

Person B's svn up makes it *up-to-date*. Hence it doesn't hit the out of date error

Comment: Which svn client are you using?

Comment: Can you use svn hooks to reduce human errors

Comment: This should not be possible. When Person B goes to commit their out of date changes they are warned by SVN that they are out of date and required to update. The only way around that is if they intentionally override it... in which case it really is human error!

Answer (score 4):

Unless I'm mistaken, SVN shouldn't allow Person B to commit if he or she does not have latest.

From red-bean:

> The repository doesn't know or care whether your changes make any
>   sense as a whole; it checks only to make sure nobody else has changed
>   any of the same files that you did when you weren't looking. If
>   somebody has done that, the entire commit will fail with a message
>   informing you that one or more of your files are out of date:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.cycle.html

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, SVN shouldn't allow this without you taking some action to force losing the work already committed.

If you do an `svn commit` and somebody else has already committed changes before you, SVN will tell you that you must do an `svn update` first.

If you then do `svn update`, SVN will merge any changes from the repository into your local working copy. Normally this just works, and you can commit. Nothing is lost.

Sometimes you both modified the same part of the same file. In this case, SVN will tell you there is a "Conflict". You MUST resolve this conflict before you commit. If you try to commit without resolving the conflict, SVN will not let you do that either. To resolve a conflict, you must first open the file and manually combine your changes with the repository changes. Normally you do this using a nice 3-way diff tool like kDiff3 or Meld or something similar which can integrate directly into SVN settings.

After you save your merged changes, and only then, you must use `svn resolve` to tell SVN that you're done doing the merge. Only then will SVN allow you to commit.

In other words, you must have messed up somewhere in how you're using SVN. This is exactly the situation SVN is designed to prevent causing problems.

Answer (score 2):

> -[Error comes in] Person B forgets to download the latest copy and start s working on his outdated copy. He then commits that and essentially erases everything person A did.

This should not be possible. Preventing this is one of the main tasks of a system like svn. In fact the command line client won't let you do this.

The only way to overwrite the changes of others is if you do it *intentionally*. Using the command line client I would have to go out of my way to commit changes that will wipe out the work of others. Maybe you closed some warning pop-ups too fast in whatever client you are using, but I don't think that qualifies as "human error".

In any case, since svn is a version control system, you cannot permanently wipe out anything. If you notice you "made a mistake" and wiped out the work of others, you can simply revert that commit to undo what you did.